# Curly brackets in OrmLite select query throws error

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

It seems like OrmLite plain select extension method (`Select<T>`) tries to format the query string (like `SelectFmt<T>`), and so it throws an error if the query string contains curly brackets, which it assumes are missing arguments.

Example query:

```
db.Select<Company>("Website='http://www.test.com/?session={123}'");
```

Error thrown:

```
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

Ideally, `Select<T>` should just execute the query verbatim, without any string formatting.

Is it a bug in OrmLite, or something else?!

**Update:** Seems like the issue is [here in OrmLiteDialectProviderBase class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L487). It should have a check for params length etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SqlList<T>` API's for [executing Custom SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) that skips pre-processing by OrmLite, but you'll need to provide the full SQL Statement, e.g:

```
var results = db.SqlList<Company>(
  "SELECT * FROM Company WHERE Website='http://www.test.com/?session={123}'");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any plans to change `Select<T>` without arguments to behave more like `SqlList<T>`?

Comment: @Nick There is no behavior in `SqlList<T>`, it exists to by pass OrmLite pre-processing, but SqlFmt now short-circuits empty params [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/57697b9c2b8cf5438cf96d3e88fc63b54119e0d2) this change is available from v4.0.53 that's [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)